# Are we using the adapter design pattern everytime we extend a class and implements its interfaces methods?

Tags: java, design-patterns

My understanding of the adapter design pattern is that we are allowing an interface from an existing class to be used as another interface.

So every time we extend or implement a class in java we are using the adapter pattern? So this bit of code here is using the adapter design pattern?

```
public class car extends flyingMachine{

  void drive(){}

  @override
  void fly(){}

}
```

There is lots of information on the pattern online but nothing that clarifies this question for me.

Comment: No. An adapter is like a *decorator* that **adapts** one type of class to another. For example, taking an existing `Car` and giving it the *ability* to [**fly**](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/e3/2a/92/e32a92e184f7fe457320b476459daeb1.png). Better [example](http://s3.crackedcdn.com/phpimages/article/6/2/5/148625_v1.jpg).

Comment: OK let me edit my question to see if I know what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- inheritance is not an adapter pattern.

Say you have your `Car` with your drive() method (which really should implement an interface say `Moveable` with the method `drive()`). Now there is some other class that take a parameter of `Moveable`.

```
public class MakeItSo
{
   public void easeOnDown(Moveable thing)
   { 
      thing.drive();
   }
}
```

Now let's say you have a cool new class `Spaceship` provided by someone else, and it has a method `warp()`. And it doesn't implement `Moveable`, but you'd like to use the `MakeItSo` class. What to do?

This is where the adapter pattern can help. In such a case, you create a new class that implements (or it could extend, but that is very confusing in many cases) the `Moveable` interface, but is:
  - Constructed using the Spaceship
  - Allows the `drive()` method to call the `warp()` method

```
public class MoveableSpaceship implements Moveable  
{  
    private Spaceship ship;

    public MoveableSpaceship(Spaceship s)
    {
       ship = s;
    } 

    @Override
    public void drive()
    {
       ship.warp();
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Spaceship enterprise = getSpaceship();  //from wherever
MoveableSpaceship ncc1701 = new MoveableSpaceship(enterprise);
MakeItSo doIt = new MakeItSo();
doIt.easeOnDown(ncc1701);
```

So, even though `MakeItSo.easeOnDown` only knew about `Moveable`, and the `Spaceship` didn't implement `Moveable`, using the adapter pattern it is now possible to use the `MakeItSo` class with a `Spaceship` object via the adapter pattern.

Note: updated class to match a comment that I originally didn't interpret correctly.

Comment: `MovableSpaceship` could be a better name, I feel.

Comment: What is the MakeItSo and easeOnDown methods have my head warped lol what are they doing?

Comment: The `MakeItSo` class has a method `easeOnDown(...)` that allows any `Moveable` object to be passed to it, and it will invoke the `drive()` method (defined in the `Moveable` interface) on the specified parameter. The point is that it is possible to *adapt* a `Spaceship` that did not implement the `Moveable` interface (and did not have a `drive()` method), into a type of object that can be used anywhere a `Moveable` object is required.

Comment: Ah, we this is a class that does not implement moveable but we want to use a spaceship in it but don't have access to its warp method? so we use our adapter to make the drive method that moveable class must implement warp the spaceship?

Comment: @NikhilVartak, good suggestion once I understood to what you were likely referring. Thanks!

Comment: @MickO'Gorman, [Adapter](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Adapter/) can be implemented as ClassAdapter(inheritence) or as ObjectAdapter(composition, MoveableSpaceship example).